# How to get serial number of laptop which has Windows XP as OS?

Tags: qt, windows-xp

I am developing a Desktop Application using QT. I am using the below Code for getting the Serial number of laptop. It is working fine for Windows 7 and Windows Vista. It is not working in Windows XP.

Code:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("wmic bios");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
QByteArray out = process.readAllStandardOutput().simplified();
```

Comment: have you tried running "wmic bios" from command prompt on this xp machine? what do you get as output?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988649/how-do-i-get-the-bios-manufacturer-and-model-in-c-without-using-wmi) it appears information retrieved from command "wmic bios" is available in the registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System
```

You can use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) to read the registry on windows

a simple example would be like

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System",
                   QSettings::NativeFormat);

QString value = settings.value("Identifier", "0").toString();
```

You will have to get the actual key your looking for(use regedit.exe to browse registry) and update the above code fragment accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First time when I did "wmic bios" on a new Windows XP VirtualBox instance it showed me "wait for installation end" and this tool restarted after successful installation (so the initial process was finished). Afterwards output is the same in Win7 and WinXP.